# magento 1.9 store displaying css issues

Tags: php, magento

I have installed a copy of my magento 1.9 store on my localhost PC as i am trying to upgrade to magento 2.  I need to transfer my products to my new store. i have installed my backup on my localhost but the sites css is all messed up.

i have cleared the cache folders but this did not help, how to fix this. I need to get this working correctly before i transfer my products from magento 1 to magento 2. I can install magento 2 easily[image: This is the problem admin side] but i can not get the magento 1 store to load correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to check where is issue?**

View the source of your page and click the css links, if it is pointed correctly it should bring you to the css page.

**Case 1:** **The problem was a missing Slash "/" at the end of the domain.**

Use the following to get both rows:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url' OR path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Then update them manually and make sure the domain has it's final "/", otherwise it will merge the domain name with the following folder name.

**Case 2:** **Update Merge Css flag**

Need go to sql manager and do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%merge%'
```

Then change values from 1 to 0 Clear cache and all will be ok

**Case 3** **Disable rewrite rule**

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10961/magento-htaccess-error

Comment: i ran the case 2 "SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%merge%'"  and then i got an error message "#1146 - Table 'mage924.core_config_data' doesn't exist"    It does exist i just checked the url had the forward slash

Comment: which magento version you have?

Comment: you mean table not exist!!

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.0.1    yes the table does exist i just got that error, not sure why as i can navigate to the core_config_data table

Comment: [link](https://gyazo.com/81a36f777c93456d9de398655762fafe)  path is clear still not solved

Comment: okay in magento root you have media folder you need to set permission 777. as well as take a backup of htaccess file on your root.and delete it.once complete ping me.

Comment: Permission has been set and the .htaccess has been deleted

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't helped either, ive even deleted every .htaccess file from all folders and still the same issue. What a nightmare, i only want to upgrade to magento 2 and i cant do that without transfering my products over or i will loose the links,

Comment: can you please send me inspect element screenshot

Comment: Your a star mate. I have now managed to sort it out :) I think it was my pc reloading cached pages. i flushed my cache and rebooted the pc and everything is now ok. i had to disable rewrites in my admin panel for links to work though